# Test failure gives incomplete error message when using short syntax

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

There are 2 syntaxes (afaik) for writing tests with RSpec:

The classic/old way:

```
  describe "when user_id is not present" do
    before { @micropost.user_id = nil }

    it "should not be valid" do
      @micropost.should_not be_valid
    end
  end
```

That gives this error when failing:

> rspec ./spec/models/micropost_spec.rb:19 # Micropost when user_id is
>   not present should not be valid

And the short syntax:

```
  describe "when user_id is not present" do
    before { @micropost.user_id = nil }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
```

That gives this error when failing:

> rspec ./spec/models/micropost_spec.rb:18 # Micropost when user_id is
>   not present

The last one is missing the "should not be valid" part.

**Is there any way to have the complete test failure message, maybe a flag I don't know about?**

Note: A more complete error message is still there no matter what:

```
  1) Micropost when user_id is not present 
     Failure/Error: it { should_not be_valid }
       expected #<Micropost id: nil, content: "Lorem ipsum", user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> not to be valid
     # ./spec/models/micropost_spec.rb:18:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

But the recap at the end is incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text you see in

> rspec ./spec/models/micropost_spec.rb:19 # Micropost<sup>1</sup> when user_id is not present<sup>2</sup> should not be valid<sup>3</sup>

and

> rspec ./spec/models/micropost_spec.rb:18 # Micropost<sup>1</sup> when user_id is not present<sup>2</sup> <sup>3</sup>

is not the error message, but the *test name*, which is a concatenation of the current test's description with all its parents' descriptions:

```
describe Micropost do # <= 1
  describe "when user_id is not present" do # <= 2
    before { @micropost.user_id = nil }

    it "should not be valid" do # <= 3
      @micropost.should_not be_valid
    end
  end
end
```

In the short (one-liner) syntax - the test itself *does not have a description*

```
describe Micropost do # <= 1
  describe "when user_id is not present" do # <= 2
    before { @micropost.user_id = nil }
    it { should_not be_valid } # <= 3 - not described!
  end
end
```

If you want to *force* a description on this test you could write it like this:

```
it('should not be valid') { should_not be_valid }
```

But this kind of beats the purpose of the one-liner, which should be self-explanatory, don't you think?